# Difference /usr/share/grub/default/grub and /etc/default/grub?

Tags: boot, grub2

What is the use of `/usr/share/grub/default/grub` vs. `/etc/default/grub` ?
Which one should I edit to make grub behave differently?
(If you are aware, what is the technical or historical reason for two distinct grub files?)

The contents of both files is the same...

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: They're not the same on my PC. I've modified `/etc/default/grub` extensively and that is the one that has an effect when you run `sudo update-grub`. Posting as a comment vs answer because I don't know why there is one in `/usr`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that all of the files in the `/usr/share` directories are example configuration files. They are files that can be copied into the `/etc` directory, the place where all your configuration files reside that are used by the system. `/etc/default/grub` is the file you edit to make your changes with `GRUB`. Once you are done making your changes to the file, you run `grub-update` to have grub update and use your new settings.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

These are the only ones I have ever really edited. The `DEFAULT` tells the OS to boot by default; never usually edit this one. The `TIMEOUT_STYLE` here tells it to hide the `GRUB` menu; to have a menu put that there. `TIMEOUT` tells grub to wait that many seconds before booting the default entry. The `CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` entry tells it to boot without text scrolling (`quiet`) and with a splash screen (`splash`); remove those to have `""` and you get to see the boot messages scrolling by when booting. Very handy to see where it is failing, and no reason to get all out of sorts if you do see the odd failure there if it does not affect the functioning of the system. The last, `CMDLINE_LINUX`, I have never really had to edit; it is where you add option(s) that need to be passed into the kernel at boot to enable functions in the kernel or to correct a quirk at boot.

Comment: nice and clear explain taught me something as well

Answer (score 4):

The file `/usr/share/grub/default/grub` is part of the package `grub2-common` while the file `/etc/default/grub` is not part of any package.

I assume that `/etc/default/grub` is copied from `/usr/share/grub/default/grub` during configuration of the package or a post-installation script, hard to tell due to lack of documentation.

The file you need to edit to make changes in your grub configuration is `/etc/default/grub`; remember to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

It makes some sense to have the original file in `/usr/share/grub/default/grub`. In case you messed up while editing `/etc/default/grub` or accidentally removed it completely, you can easily recreate a fresh `/etc/default/grub` by copying from `/usr/share/grub/default/grub`.

Comment: The points about the source package being `grub2-common` and the tip to recreate the `grub` file by copying from `/usr/share/grub/default/grub` augment the answer I accepted.